# Calculus of variations: the inside function has an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, partial-derivative

It is known that if the functional 
$$J=\int_a^b L(x,f(x))dx \tag{1}$$ 
has an extremum, then the Euler equation $\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{f(x)}}=0$ holds. 
My question is, for example, what if 
$$L(x,f(x))=f(x) \int_a^b xf(x)dx~~ ? \tag{2}$$

(1) It seems to me that $\int_a^b xf(x)dx$ is still a function w.r.t $x$ and $f(x)$ denoted by $L(x,f(x))$.

(2) What is the corresponding Euler equation? Specifically, how to calculate $$\frac{\partial{[\int_a^b xf(x)dx]}}{\partial{f(x)}}~~~? \tag{3}$$

My question is similar to a previous post [Calculus of Variations: Contains an integral of my goal function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/calculus-of-variations-contains-an-integral-of-my-goal-function?rq=1), which can be concluded that: the goal function has an integral of $f(x)$.

Comment: chain rule? ${}{}$

Comment: As stated, you have $L(x,f(x)) = (f(x))^2 \, \int_a^b (y - x) \, dy = (f(x))^2 \, ( (b^2 - a^2)/2 + (b - a) \, x )$. Then, you can use an Euler equation.

Comment: I made a mistake, $L(x,f(x))$ should be $f(x)\int_a^b xf(x)dx$, for instance.